# Azure devops CI/CD docker build COPY Failed Path not found

Tags: c#, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0, docker-build

I am hosting my own build-agent on my on-premises windows server.
However, when I either try to build my docker image using the default agent or my on-premisses agent, it cannot copy the .cproj files.

What I want, is to be able to build this image without the errors.
What I have tried so far is:

- Changes work directory to: ../ , ../../ and ~/
- Google for solutions, but this does not result in anything, because it is too specific or something.

Please note that it also does not work on an agent from DevOps itself (windows-2022)
Does anyone know what I could have done wrong or overlooked?

Directories:
src/Server/DockerFile
src/Server/Server.csproj
And so on for the other .csproj files

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5005;http://+:5006
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5005
EXPOSE 5006

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /
COPY ["src/Server/Server.csproj", "src/Server/"]
COPY ["src/Application/Application.csproj", "src/Application/"]
COPY ["src/Domain/Domain.csproj", "src/Domain/"]
COPY ["src/Shared/Shared.csproj", "src/Shared/"]
COPY ["src/Infrastructure.Shared/Infrastructure.Shared.csproj", "src/Infrastructure.Shared/"]
COPY ["src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["src/Client/Client.csproj", "src/Client/"]
COPY ["src/Client.Infrastructure/Client.Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Client.Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/Server/Server.csproj" --disable-parallel
COPY . .
WORKDIR "src/Server"
RUN dotnet build "Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
WORKDIR /app/Files
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DeDenDannenburcht.Server.dll"]
```

My Pipeline

[image: Devops pipeline]

Pipeline Output

```
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" build -f F:\agents\_work\1\s\src\Server\Dockerfile -t dedendannenburcht:166 --label com.azure.dev.image.system.teamfoundationcollectionuri=https://dev.azure.com/JeremiedevosBusiness/ --label com.azure.dev.image.build.sourceversion=ab657210c8696881754f36393adee9da7394ea19 --label image.base.ref.name=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 --label image.base.digest=sha256:545da8027d0de13ac88716fc380201f05ad9b4834b5b2fd95eadf277e51318a7 F:\agents\_work\1\s\src\Server
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:5cec5c1a6e883854d5ef516a04f7fbc4f77cc63f74549820c4d061dbb560e514
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.31kB done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:8f7ecf610ac80d8ac3c3e64e4de2e264ecf11892bf7afc5ff6debe41dd69161b
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#4 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
#4 sha256:ac4494cbca04ddb415c76edcbcc7688784c2a6ea65dd656286c013738aa3b75f
#4 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
#3 sha256:9eb4f6c3944cfcbfe18b9f1a753c769fc35341309a8d4a21f8937f47e94c712b
#3 DONE 0.1s

#5 [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
#5 sha256:50f1ddc10932c4a74c7af5704e931a9489c710faea4f2381fe2380827a900e00
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app
#6 sha256:bc3cf6c390e5fe0e66017b4845c8fcf3e56c7adac9f514a00c2c986024f377a4
#6 CACHED

#7 [final 1/4] WORKDIR /app
#7 sha256:3baba3edbb555769ad9a49e827de88d7dcc4f72ad6e2b42e576964e4a30eac96
#7 CACHED

#8 [build  1/14] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0@sha256:a3dd4dee05cd1369014244d03b28b602e6a2e1650210dd8633322e00379471ec
#8 sha256:ff704f84298cdcbd6cd764720a2e1a4dcd4b44ff415133896e77ad0c5d908001
#8 resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0@sha256:a3dd4dee05cd1369014244d03b28b602e6a2e1650210dd8633322e00379471ec done
#8 sha256:0af6b8199917326984baa1452533da610b46f65bfbc5296c7f81cb72d3beec84 2.01kB / 2.01kB done
#8 sha256:dc243ad423c72b21b838c1362ca152823b0b379a546887d8c47c437357576fb2 7.31kB / 7.31kB done
#8 sha256:664e00cfda3df2ac7370c116f04a17d636fc041b62bdd9a0b88a60b987344269 0B / 136.50MB 0.1s
#8 sha256:a3dd4dee05cd1369014244d03b28b602e6a2e1650210dd8633322e00379471ec 2.17kB / 2.17kB done
#8 sha256:4253139ebd4dcee5f7878254306eb794d0f2a80ee4ca8d085d0b9e507412fb1e 0B / 25.36MB 0.1s

#10 sha256:aa96c6c99b71465c230e63fb1edea0588e2b25c39d6b44fc1381e7cbe48c15d9
#10 ERROR: "/src/Server/Server.csproj" not found: not found

#13 [build  5/14] COPY [src/Shared/Shared.csproj, src/Shared/]
#13 sha256:8fd70ae770f73428f5ff667da9b5080dff2b8035dbeb1247fe9e76d5890ad27d
#13 ERROR: "/src/Shared/Shared.csproj" not found: not found

#16 [build  8/14] COPY [src/Client/Client.csproj, src/Client/]
#16 sha256:33c15418c5097a788d8ef568338206ce45e5fea62b707a2be13c136b28ca43e9
#16 ERROR: "/src/Client/Client.csproj" not found: not found

#15 [build  7/14] COPY [src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj, src/Infrastructure/]
#15 sha256:4f643811b59a89db4a864a2a40a7ff2cc05709c3b123027874b72ff436af0d56
#15 ERROR: "/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj" not found: not found

#17 [build  9/14] COPY [src/Client.Infrastructure/Client.Infrastructure.csproj, src/Client.Infrastructure/]
#17 sha256:b7385969b745977db24f702bc1c8f0b931cd675b9f44e70870ae2d918632e9b3
#17 ERROR: "/src/Client.Infrastructure/Client.Infrastructure.csproj" not found: not found

#14 [build  6/14] COPY [src/Infrastructure.Shared/Infrastructure.Shared.csproj, src/Infrastructure.Shared/]
#14 sha256:f101a94226cbf6f38fe9d908da512ded2bd68070207a6dd5c003d8967252c970
#14 ERROR: "/src/Infrastructure.Shared/Infrastructure.Shared.csproj" not found: not found

#12 [build  4/14] COPY [src/Domain/Domain.csproj, src/Domain/]
#12 sha256:152a7025db6bab6e2e456a9ab7ef8436cc9689411341ea38c362df78a0d058c1
#12 ERROR: "/src/Domain/Domain.csproj" not found: not found

#11 [build  3/14] COPY [src/Application/Application.csproj, src/Application/]
#11 sha256:1760818b73b46bb8ebf75492933a413de08fd2ab7a26cae37de4ae4a5f60b83e
#11 ERROR: "/src/Application/Application.csproj" not found: not found
------
 > [build  2/14] COPY [src/Server/Server.csproj, src/Server/]:
------
------
 > [build  3/14] COPY [src/Application/Application.csproj, src/Application/]:
------
------
 > [build  4/14] COPY [src/Domain/Domain.csproj, src/Domain/]:
------
------
 > [build  5/14] COPY [src/Shared/Shared.csproj, src/Shared/]:
------
------
 > [build  6/14] COPY [src/Infrastructure.Shared/Infrastructure.Shared.csproj, src/Infrastructure.Shared/]:
------
------
 > [build  7/14] COPY [src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj, src/Infrastructure/]:
------
------
 > [build  8/14] COPY [src/Client/Client.csproj, src/Client/]:
------
------
 > [build  9/14] COPY [src/Client.Infrastructure/Client.Infrastructure.csproj, src/Client.Infrastructure/]:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/src/Client.Infrastructure/Client.Infrastructure.csproj" not found: not found
##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Build an image
```

Comment: Could you pls try what happens when replacing `WORKDIR /` by `WORKDIR /src` and removing all `src/` segments in the `COPY` commands?

Comment: @mu88 then I get the same error, but with the changed path.

Comment: Then I would reduce the `Dockerfile` step by step until it builds again and maybe combine it with some `ls` output

Comment: Hmm yeah, worth a try, but dont think i will find much.

Comment: Another option would be to provide a GitHub repo with your project structure (no actual code, just `Dockerfile` and `csproj` files) so that I can play around

Comment: That would much appreciated! This is the template, https://github.com/blazorhero/CleanArchitecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dockerfile` is located under `src\Server`. The *Build an image* step calls `docker build -f .\src\Server\Dockerfile .\src\Server` which will not work because that is already one level too deep in the directory tree.

So there are several options:

- Call `docker build -f .\src\Server\Dockerfile .` from the **root directory**, but use a custom shell script rather than the official *Build an image* step - it seems to have that kind of limitation.
- Use relative paths in the `Dockerfile` like this:

```
COPY ["../src/Server/Server.csproj", "src/Server/"]
```

- Move the `Dockerfile` to the root directory.

Comment: How can i implement that from the Devops pipeline?  It is working when i build it locally and just build the image. The main problem is that the same DockerFile that works locally does not work when build by a devops agent.

Comment: Can you pls add the YAML content of the _Build an image_ step to your question? I wanna see whether we can override the working dir, because that bold-ish argument is the problem: "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" build -f F:\agents\_work\1\s\src\Server\Dockerfile ...  __F:\agents\_work\1\s\src\Server__

Comment: This is the Yaml File:
steps:
- task: Docker@0
  displayName: 'Build an image'
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryConnection: 'Docker Hub Dev'
    dockerFile: src/Server/Dockerfile

Comment: I see. Maybe that's a limitation of the Docker build step. I suggest to move the `Dockerfile` to the root directory

Comment: Mu88 that has seemed to work, thank you enormously for helping me out with this. If you add or edit a solution i will happily mark it as the solution. Wy devops does not like nested DockerFiles is a question to me, even when i escaped to the parent folders it did not work. Have a great day!

Comment: It was a pleasure to help you  maybe you can file an issue?

Answer (score 1):

this may happend because the docker file in sub-directory and not within the root.
by default the task  DockerBuild is running from the directory where the Dockerfile exist.
You have to change the buildContext to . so it will execute from the root folder,   good luck

> ```
>           buildContext: "."
> ```

for example:

```
        - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build and push docker image
        inputs:
          command: buildAndPush
          arguments: '--no-cache'
          repository: ca-devops/bigcommerce-fpm
          Dockerfile: "./some-wird-directory/Dockerfile"
          buildContext: "."
          ${{ if in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master', 'main') }}:
            tags: |
              $(semVer)
          ${{ else }}:
            tags: |
              $(semVer)
```

[Azur Devops - Docker@2 - Docker v2 task - Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml)